# Knockout.js foreach error

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

TLDR: Knockout doesn't understand the binding in `options` when it is in a foreach context.

I have the following HTML:

```
<!-- ko foreach: getModelData(123).Filters.Products.ORDER -->
        <div class="row Filter">
            <div class="col-7">
                <select required data-bind="options: $root.getModelData(123).DataSets.Products_ORDER,
                optionsText: $root.getModelData(123).DataSets.Products_ORDER.Text,
                optionsValue: $root.getModelData(123).DataSets.Products_ORDER.Field,
                value: Field"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-3">    
                <select required data-bind="value: Order"> 
                        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose...</option>
                        <option value="ASC">Ascending</option>
                        <option value="DESC">Descending</option>
                </select>    
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
                <a href=""><img src="images/CmdDelete.svg" alt="remove" width="20" height="20"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Now, the `getModelData(123)` is a custom function within the viewModel that is bound to this entire thing. It basically returns a subset of the viewModel. 
The data that acompanies this structure is something like this:

```
{
Filters: {
  Products: {
    ORDER: [],
    WHERE: [],
    LIMIT: [],
    },
  someMoreDatasets...
},
DataSets:{
  Products: { /* some data, irrelevant for this */}
  Products_ORDER: [
    {Field: "value", Text: "Option 1"},
    {Field: "valu2", Text: "Option 2"}
    ]
  }
}
```

*Disclaimer: This is all hand typed so there might be some 'textual errors' but they are most likely not the cause of the error I get on the page because it is all drawn from a database.*

### **The IDEA is:**

There is a button which allows you to "add more filters" to your data.
Whenever this button is pressed, a new object that looks like `{Filter: "", Order: ""}` is pushed to an observable array located here: `Filters.Products.ORDER` which is the array which should contain the information about what filters the client selected. Meanwhile, the `select` within this HTML is bound to an array located here: `DataSets.Products_ORDER` from which it draws the information on what the possible selection options are.

This, due to foreach binding, creates a new set of HTML tags for your filtering. It creates a filter like shown below. This filter was created by the button press so it `foreach` binding works.

[image]

This dropdown-box is even populated by the correct amount of objects (though their display is not as expected, so this is **issue#1**) which leads me to believe that the binding syntax for the `options` on the select is correct, but why does the same syntax when going 1 level deeper not display properly, i do not know.

The **issue#2** comes in the `binding` of the `Field` value, which might be fixed automatically when issue#1 is resolved. When the `add new filter` is pressed. The knockout throws an error that goes like:

[image]

This binding is on the same `select` element within the foreach loop, and is suppose to reference the element on which the loop is being executed on. But for some reason the entire object is not seen or it is not in context.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** So yeah typically.... been bugging me the whole day, as soon as I post it I found the issue (at least partially). The `Field` binding thing is fixed. Was suppose to be a `Filter` since the dataset used for binding the foreach doenst have a `Field` but a `Filter` instead. The `[Object object]` issue still remains though, ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your option binding:

```
<select required data-bind="options: $root.getModelData(123).DataSets.Products_ORDER,
            optionsText: 'Text',
            optionsValue: 'Field',
            value: Filter"></select>
```

Comment: Well thanks for the answer! Fixed it partially but not entierly. Namely, the `select` no longer displays `[Object object]` but it doesnt show the text either. The value shown is proper in the HTML inspector

Comment: Really? Could you get a fiddle going for it? So in the inspector you can see the Values, the text is just blank?

Comment: The values in the inspector are blank, yup, though at this point, since the `optionsValue` works, I am inclined to believe it is a server/db issue more likely. Will check with the DB Admin when he is back from launch break, then report back

Comment: replace $root.getModelData(123).DataSets.Products_ORDER with [
    {Field: "value", Text: "Option 1"},
    {Field: "valu2", Text: "Option 2"}
    ] to test. I do no that knockout does not appreciate double dotting, and in many places ive had to use withs to get it down to the property, in your case: options: Products_ORDER

Comment: Okay it worked like that so it is most likely the dataset error not getting the proper fields from the database, I can't check that though, no permissions. As far as the issue is concerned, this answer does answer the original problem so I am marking it as "Accepted". Cheers